# Forcing the Android emulator to store changes to /system to preserve root

Tags: android, android-emulator, root, android-7.0-nougat, xposed

I am using Nougat 7 emulator and was able to root the emulator. But after rebooting all the changes i made to android /system folder are gone. Is there any way to preserve the /system. **My real objective is to install xposed on Nougat 7 android emulator** .

Answer (score 0):

When you start the Android emulator the system partition comes from a shared image located in the Android SDK. Search for `system.img` in the subdirectory `system-images/android-??/default`

If you want to change something on the system partition I would suggest to do the following:

1. Copy `system.img` file
2. Modify it outside of the emulator (uncompress, mount, modify, recompress, see [on this page section "SYSTEM.IMG"](http://omappedia.org/wiki/Android_eMMC_Booting#Modifying_.IMG_Files) for details)
3. Use the modified `system.img` to start/create a new AVD instance.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Let me try the same.